# User login doesn't work after server migration

Tags: 7

We had a Drupal 7 site running on PHP 5.6. We have moved this site to another server running on PHP 7.4.

When I navigate to /user/login, type my username and password, and click on *Submit*, I'm redirected to /users/myusername, but it says *Access Denied* and it doesn't show the top bar to change configuration, content, etc. I had also checked the *sessions* table and it stores the new session with the user ID.

> [image: screenshot]

No session ID has been stored in cookies after I log in.

> [image: screenshot]

I had tried so many ways, but nothing helped me.

1. I checked that mod_rewrite is enabled
2. I tried with and without *Base URL* setting in the *settings.php* file
3. I tried with and without `RewriteBase` setting in the *.htaccess* file
4. I tried with and without `cookie_domain` setting in the *settings.php* file

I am surprised that, when I tried to migrate another website to the same server with another sub-directory, the login worked fine.

They are Drupal 7 sites migrated to the same server but on different sub-directories.

Why doesn't the login work in one of the sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of debug I found the issue in settings.php file

```
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
```

for HTTPS site the session cookie must be secure but as the current site is HTTP, so we need to turn off this feature by

```
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 0);
```

Now, login is working fine.